# How do I stub an event emitter with Sinon.js

Tags: javascript, mocking, stub, sinon

I am trying to stub the following:

```
on('complete', function(data){ });
```

I only want to call the callback if the first parameter is 'complete'.

The function I am testing also contains:

```
on('error', function(data){ });
```

So I can't just do yield cause that will fire both the complete and the error callback.

If I wouldn't use sinon I would fake it by writing the following.

```
var on = function(event, callback){
  if (event === 'complete'){
    callback('foobar');
  };
};
```

Comment: Can you show a more full example of the function containing this?

Answer (score 9):

You can narrow the circumstances under which a `yield` occurs by combining it with a `withArgs` like so...

```
on.withArgs('complete').yields(valueToPassToCompleteCallback);
on.withArgs('error').yields(valueToPassToErrorCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a [spyCall](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#spycall):

```
var spy = sinon.spy(window, 'on');
on('error', function(data){ });
on('complete', function(data){ });
for(var i=0; i < spy.callCount; i++){
    var call = spy.getCall(i);
    if(call.args[0] === 'complete') call.args[1]('foobar');
}
```